# jQuery's getJSON not working with REST end

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I have a REST end of my API at the following address : http://test.jll.aplikacje-dedykowane.pl/rest/warehouse/all . Now I'm trying to return the JSON data prepared at this page but I'm constantly getting null (with 200 OK) as a result.

```
var getSearchResults = function(){
    var url = '',
    data = '';      
    url = 'http://test.jll.aplikacje-dedykowane.pl/rest/warehouse/all';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into the [same site origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), assuming that url is outside of the domain that calling it.

Comment: yap, you were right. jsonp and tunes on the server site solved the problem.